# Custom title for links on contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

- I am working on an app which saves users social networks links in the default `contacts` app provided by `Android OS`.
- I am able to save link in the app but I am not able to customize the title as you can check in the image below of **Default Contacts App**:

[image]

- I am using below code to save linkedin url as an example for now but I want to save it as ***linkedin*** title instead of ***Website*** and also linkedin icon.

> Current Code block:

```
    if (loginResponseData.getLinkedin() != null) {
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactid);
         values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
         values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.DATA, loginResponseData.getLinkedin()); 
            fragmentActivity.getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each Data type you want to persist into the Database, you should go into the documentation and check which fields it supports and you might want to fill them in your insert call.

You can check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website

That `CommonDataKinds.Website` supports the fields URL, TYPE and LABEL.
The text that appears below the url in the contacts app is the label field.

So your code can look something like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactid);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Website.URL, loginResponseData.getLinkedin()); 
values.put(Website.TYPE, Website.TYPE_CUSTOM); // when this is set to CUSTOM, the contacts app will display the label field
values.put(Website.LABEL, "Linkedin"); 

contentResolver.insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: I tried you code but it is still showing **Website**.

Comment: if you already have that link in that raw-contact, you'll need to remove it first, and then insert it. The code doesn't update existing websites, only inserts a new row.

Comment: Yes. I have tried after deleting contact but no luck.

Comment: are you able to change that text when you edit that contact manually from the contacts app by updating the "Label" field?

Comment: I am able to update `work` , `home` label name setting any custom label from Contacts App. But for website none is available.

Comment: that means this is product decision by the makers of your contacts app. I just verified it myself and see the same for Google Contacts and Samsung Contacts, but the data IS THERE in the DB and can be shown with a different contacts app (e.g. Contacts+). So basically the API supports what you want, but your Contacts app doesn't

Comment: I have also tried with `emulator` but it still shows website. Do you know any different tag instead of `Website` that can be used.